# Java Adapter .mts Parsing

Tags: java, xml-parsing, adapter, hana, mts

I am trying to write an adapter to parse data from an mts file and I don't know where to start

the adapter should create virtual tables with the metadata and filter it whenever it recieves a SQL statement to do so.

the mts file raw data has keys for each attribute to tell what type it is.(" for strings, % for numbers ) .

Comment: This shouldnt be your place to start my friend. This should be the place you come after you did homework, research and have a specific direction we can help you with... to "find you a direction" you can use google, chatGPT...

Answer (score 0):

This question is very vague and the commentators correctly point out, that there should be more preparation on the OP's end.

The best starting point for that preparation is checking the SAP documentation on developing your own adapters for SDI:

[Data Provisioning Adapter SDK Guide](https://help.sap.com/docs/HANA_SMART_DATA_INTEGRATION/e974128d984d4bfeaa0c0b582ce24d79/d4b02f02b92a4242a57a6d1a9b84ea7c.html?locale=en-US)

This documentation contains examples for how to build, install and use custom SDI adapters.